Gitlab with SSH behind HAProxy
I have GitLab configuration with HAProxy as a reverse proxy server. With current settings haproxy redirects https requests to gitlab backend and it works fine. The problem is how to redirect ssh requests? Users can use https for commits but can`t use ssh in this configuration.
How to make working https and ssh together?

Is this all on the same system, or do you have an HAProxy node in front of one or more GitLab servers? Which operating system, and which version/distro?

HAProxy is in front of Gitlab

I`ve solved my problem by installing sslh on the server and adding frontend for tcp connections in haproxy

As ssh is a complete different Protocol then HTTPS isn't there such a mechanism like "redirect" in ssh.
As you mentioned that you use HTTPS & SSH on the same HAProxy instance could this blog article help you to create a ssh reverse proxy with HAProxy.
https://www.haproxy.com/blog/route-ssh-connections-with-haproxy
The steps are:

Create a TCP Listener (frontend/listen)
Use the ProxyCommand in SSH to connect to the reverse proxy.

